# AttributeError 'pyparsing' on executing the update-manager

Tags: update-manager, python3

My `update-manager` in Ubuntu 18.04. had been working fine, until it suddenly showed an error:

`AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'`

How can I bring my *Update Manager* to work again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there has been changes in the module `pyparsing` where the attribute `pp.downcaseTokens` is now to be found under `pp.pyparsing_common.downcase_tokens` (See discussion in GitHub [AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens' #207](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/207))

So the quick fix is following:

1. Open the file `auth.py` with a text editor—I personally used the lightweight `mousepad`. The location of `auth.py` is given with the message error. In my case, it was located in the local package `httplib2` of python, that is, `/home/lovedByJesus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/auth.py`
2. Replace `pp.downcaseTokens` by `pp.pyparsing_common.downcase_tokens` (I found this expression in line 20 belonging to the assignment `auth_param_name = token.copy().setName("auth-param-name").addParseAction(pp.downcaseTokens)`)
3. Save the file and run `update-manager`. It should run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the expression containing "pp.downcaseTokens" found in one of the Python `site-packages` files, I just ran:

`pip install 'httplib2>=0.20.2'`

as suggested by one of the answers found [here](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/207#issuecomment-951282767).

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thanks for alternative answer in Ubuntu 22.04. Take heed that I asked for Ubuntu 18.04., and it works with python3.6 as distro version, but in Ubuntu 22.04 you got python3.10 see [chat](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/sehecb/will_2204_lts_ship_with_python_310/)